# Moving processed files to another directory using Spring integration ftp inbound adapter

Tags: spring, ftp, spring-integration

I am trying to poll local directory using ftp inbound adapter to fetch files for further processing. I want to move the file to another local directory and delete it from origination. Not getting a way to achieve it. Here's what I have so far:

```
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
    channel="ftpChannel" session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    filename-pattern="*.xml" auto-create-local-directory="false"
    delete-remote-files="false" remote-directory="/" local-directory="//C://FBS//testmq">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="20000" />
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="ftpChannel">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use transaction synchronization with a pseudo transaction manager; see the [file example in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/transactions.html#transaction-synchronization). Here's the configuration from that section of the docs:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="inputDirPoller"
    channel="someChannel"
    directory="/foo/bar"
    filter="filter"
    comparator="testComparator">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="5000">
        <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" synchronization-factory="syncFactory" />
    </int:poller>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
    <int:after-commit expression="payload.renameTo(new java.io.File('/success/' + payload.name))" 
           channel="committedChannel" />
    <int:after-rollback expression="payload.renameTo(new java.io.File('/failed/' + payload.name))"
           channel="rolledBackChannel" />
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>
```

Continue reading into the next section...

> Referring to the above section, you may be thinking it would be useful to take these 'success' or 'failure' actions when a flow completes, even if there is no 'real' transactional resources (such as JDBC) downstream of the poller. For example, consider a  followed by an ftp:outbout-channel-adapter/. Neither of these components is transactional but we might want to move the input file to different directories, based on the success or failure of the ftp transfer.
>
> To provide this functionality, the framework provides a PseudoTransactionManager, enabling the above configuration even when there is no real transactional resource involved. If the flow completes normally, the beforeCommit and afterCommit synchronizations will be called, on failure the afterRollback will be called. Of course, because it is not a real transaction there will be no actual commit or rollback. The pseudo transaction is simply a vehicle used to enable the synchronization features.

Comment: @Gary Russell - Is there a way to auto-create the success/failed directories? Thanks.

Comment: Not with SpEL - you can remove the `expression` s and the `File` will be sent to the success/failure channel - you can then add a subflow on those channels - add a service activator to create the directory and rename the file.

Comment: How did you use this in code level? @Autowired
 @Qualifier("committedChannel")
 PollableChannel localProcessedChannel; I am trying to send this file to another folder, but no luck, can you please help me?

Comment: Do exactly "what" at the code level? It's better to ask a new question with more details of exactly what you need, than trying to piggy-back on an existing question.

Comment: @GaryRussell ... does the syncFactory object works after the entire message was processed through the  entire flow or just after it was commited on "someChannel" ?

Comment: As long as there is no async handoff (no queue channels, no task executors), it runs when the flow completes - when the thread returns to the  poller.

Comment: This did not remove the file when I used that expression.  I need to change it to payload.renameTo(new java.io.File('/success/' + payload.name)