# Using spring PseudoTransactionManager to move processed files

Tags: spring-integration

This looks like a duplicate question, I have looked at [the question here about transaction managers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151642/how-to-move-processed-file-to-another-directory-using-spring-integration-ftp-inb), and the referred documentation section, but have not been successful.

The flow I have in mind is for processing xml files:

Inbound Channel Adapter with Transaction Manager -> Channel -> Service-Activator

The file is passed into my java program for processing just fine. I then want the transaction manager part to then move processed files into one folder and failed files into another. The latter part is my problem. I have this configuration:

```xml
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="pgen-inbound" directory="file:D:/records/incoming/" auto-startup="true" filter="compositeFilter" channel="pgen-inchannel">
  <int:poller fixed-rate="1000">
    <int:transactional transaction-manager="transactionManager" synchronization-factory="fileSync"/>
  </int:poller>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.integration.transaction.PseudoTransactionManager"/>

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="fileSync">
  <int:after-commit expression="payload.renameTo('./success/' + payload.name)" channel="nullChannel" />
  <int:after-rollback expression="payload.renameTo('./failed/' + payload.name)" channel="nullChannel" />
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>

<int:channel id="pgen-inchannel"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="pgen-inchannel" ref="recordProcessor" method="processInboundRecords"/>

<bean id="recordProcessor" class="com.a.b.RecordFeeder">
  <property name="username" value="pgenuser"/>
  <property name=".../>
  ...
</bean>

<bean id="compositeFilter" class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
  <constructor-arg>
    <list>
      <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.SimplePatternFileListFilter">
        <constructor-arg value="*.xml"/>
      </bean>
    </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The directories all exist, but the file is not moved and there are no error messages, just logging:

```
INFO org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource- Created message: [GenericMessage [payload=D:\records\incoming\record2.xml, headers={id=f24b11e4-39ac-03e1-6b3c-cae7ff5b7615, timestamp=1468404043936}]]
```

My understanding is that I do not need channels onwards from the transaction-synchronisation-factory, as they would just be passed the outcomes of the payload.renameTo operations, ie. true or false, hence I used nullChannel there.

I get this logging:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler- handler 'ServiceActivator for [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@1e05e138] (org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0)' produced no reply for request Message: GenericMessage [payload=D:\records\incoming\pgImpor2.xml, headers={id=4860011b-b6a3-9dbd-8572-90b12de88e9c, timestamp=1468423768506}]
DEBUG org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel- postSend (sent=true) on channel 'pgen-inbound', message: GenericMessage [payload=D:\records\incoming\pgImpor2.xml, headers={id=4860011b-b6a3-9dbd-8572-90b12de88e9c, timestamp=1468423768506}]
DEBUG org.springframework.integration.transaction.ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor- Sending received message to org.springframework.integration.channel.NullChannel@4fc66eb8 as part of 'beforeCommit' transaction synchronization
DEBUG org.springframework.integration.channel.NullChannel- message sent to null channel: GenericMessage [payload=D:\record\incoming\pgImpor2.xml, headers={id=4860011b-b6a3-9dbd-8572-90b12de88e9c, timestamp=1468423768506}]
DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager- Initiating transaction commit
DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager- Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@36411551]
DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager- Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@36411551] for JPA transaction
DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager- Participating in existing transaction
DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager- Found thread-bound EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@36411551] for JPA transaction
DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager- Participating in existing transaction
**DEBUG org.springframework.integration.transaction.ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor- Evaluating afterCommit expression: 'payload.renameTo('./success/' + payload.name)' on GenericMessage [payload=D:\record\incoming\pgImpor2.xml, headers={id=4860011b-b6a3-9dbd-8572-90b12de88e9c, timestamp=1468423768506}]**
DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory- Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationEvaluationContext'
DEBUG org.springframework.integration.transaction.ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor- Sending expression result message to nullChannel as part of 'afterCommit' transaction synchronization
DEBUG org.springframework.integration.channel.NullChannel- message sent to null channel: GenericMessage [payload=false, headers={id=339dda35-55cc-c6db-68e5-fc84fe32ff04, timestamp=1468423781333}]
DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager- Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@36411551] after transaction
DEBUG org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils- Closing JPA EntityManager
```

So it evaluates the renameTo call for the success case.. but without any result as it is set up.

Comment: First step is to turn on DEBUG logging for `o.s.i` and watch the message flow.

Comment: Thank you. It appears to evaluate the renameTo call, but without any immediate result. I tried attaching an outbound file adapter, but it reasonably complains that it cannot convert the boolean return value into a file.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `without any immediate result` - it's either successful or not; if the rename failed (`false`) then something is causing the rename to fail - security, bad directory etc.

Comment: renameTo is not successful (payload=false; first I thought that just meant no payload), but there are no reasons logged. I will try debugging into the expression evaluation routines to see what is going on then.

Comment: Ah, the renameTo is the actual java File.renameTo, which sometimes has a similar approach to error messaging as Oracle. In this case it was the paths as I misunderstood from the example that the paths I should provide for the renameTo call were relative to the incoming file location, which they are not. SpEL like this inspired from another answer of yours worked: payload.renameTo(payload.toPath().resolveSibling('success') + '/' + payload.name) Thank you.