# Spring Integration, how to better describe validation component

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-integration

My flow is defined like

```
return IntegrationFlows.from(
(MessageSourceSpec<?, ? extends MessageSource<?>>) Files.inboundAdapter(directory)
           .autoCreateDirectory(false)
           .patternFilter("*.xml"),
  e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1000)) )) 
  .transform(new TransformXmlToMyDocument())
  .transform(new DataValidator())  // VALIDATOR
  .transform(new TransformMyDocumentToRabbitDomain())
  .channel(pubSubRabbitOutput)
  .get();
```

Question is about the validator. Currently the validator I made as a "transparent" transformer that throws if data inside message are not valid. The whole flow will be wrapped in pseudo-transaction to handle error as suggested in "[how to move processed file to another directory using Spring integration ftp inbound adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30151642/how-to-move-processed-file-to-another-directory-using-spring-integration-ftp-inb)".

But what would be the best way to include a logical validator in the Flow? Should it be transfomer or other kind of flow component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Filter EIP](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Filter.html). And of course Spring Integration provides [one](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#filter) on the matter.

You `DataValidator` must return `true/false` for the condition and there is `throw-exception-on-rejection` option for your discard logic:

```
 .filter(new DataValidator(), "validate", e -> e.throwExceptionOnRejection(true))
```

Comment: Thanks Artem! However, our validator would need to propagate further (to error channel handler) some error information  - what specifically was invalid. How we can achieve this?

Comment: Good point! So, your `DataValidator` can throw an exception and you can use `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to catch and send to the `failureChannel` for processing